# Evaluation of Definite Integral Involving Cubic Power of a Binomial

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

I am seeking assistance in evaluating the following definite integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{( ^2 + 1)^3} x$$

[Contour of the following integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47z7L.png)

I have attempted various approaches, but I haven't been successful in finding a closed-form solution.

Could someone provide guidance on how to approach this integral and possibly compute its value? Any insights, alternative methods, or relevant references would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Feel free to customize the question based on any specific details or context you'd like to add.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos , thanks!

Comment: Hint: in the notation of your linked diagram, can you see why $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{dz}{(z^2+1)^3}=0$, while the integral you want is $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\mu_R}\frac{dz}{(z^2+1)^3}$? If so, you just need [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since given function is even, we can just evaluate the integral from 0 to infinity and double it.

Let $\ t = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Then, $\ dx = \frac{-dt}{2t^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

Substituting $\ t$ throughout, we get:

$$\ I = \int_{\ 1}^{0} t^3 \cdot \frac{-dt}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

$$ = \int_{\ 0}^{\ 1} t^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-t)^{\frac{-1}{2}}dt$$
$$ = \ B(\frac{5}{2},\frac{1}{2})$$

Where $\ B(x,y)$ is the Beta function.

Evaluating, we get

$$\ I = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{5}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(3)}$$

$$\ I = \frac{\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \cdot \sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

$$\ I = \frac{3\pi}{8}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{( ^2 + a)^3} x \\
=&\ \frac12\frac{d^2}{da^2} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ ^2 + a} x\right)_{a=1}
= \frac12\frac{d^2}{da^2} \left(\frac\pi{\sqrt a}\right)_{a=1}= \frac{3\pi}8
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

HINT…try substituting $$x=\tan\theta.$$ The resulting integral is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Especially if you know$$8\cos^4\theta=3+4\cos2\theta+\cos4\theta.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint!!!